# SQL - Select from multiple tables with no results in one of them

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, many-to-many

I think this question may have been answered before, but I can't find it: all results I've found are not a solution to this problem...

Let's suppose my database has the following tables and relations (and I can't change them):

- Entities: user, workgroup and queue
- One user can be contained into many workgroups, one workgroup can have many users.
- One workgroup can have many queues, one queue can belong to many workgroups.
- There are two tables making these "many to many" relations: m2m_user_wg, m2m_wg_queue

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT U.LOGIN, WG.WORKGROUP, Q.QUEUE
FROM USER U, M2M_USER_WG MUW, WORKGROUP W, M2M_WG_QUEUE MWQ, QUEUE Q
WHERE U.ID = MUW.WORKGROUP2USER
AND W.ID = MUW.USER2WORKGROUP
AND W.ID = MWQ.QUEUE2WORKGROUP
AND Q.ID = MWQ.WORKGROUP2QUEUE
AND U.LOGIN = 'johndoe'
```

This query works fine when all entities have existing values, but let's suppose a user has only one workgroup, and that workgroup doesn't have any queue. The ID of the workgroup won't exist in the table M2M_WG_QUEUE (MWQ), so the query won't display results.

What I want is to see the user and his workgroups even if some of them have no queues. Something like this:

```
USER      WORKGROUP    QUEUE
johndoe   WG3          Q7
johndoe   WG3          Q8
johndoe   WG4          Q7
johndoe   WG9
```

In the example above, the result should be something like this:

```
USER      WORKGROUP    QUEUE
johndoe   WG6
```

How can I do that? I think it maybe can be done with a join or (+), but I've tried it in several ways and non of them worked...

Comment: You are using inner joins (well, cross joins actually that your `WHERE` clause turns into inner joins, because you are using an out-dated join syntax that we used in the 1980s), where you only get matches. You want an outer join instead, where you keep a row even when the joined table has no match for it. Look up joins (especially `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) in your manual. By the way: always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.  Pro

Your problem is that you need a `LEFT JOIN`, presumably:

```
SELECT U.LOGIN, WG.WORKGROUP, Q.QUEUE
FROM USER U LEFT JOIN
     M2M_USER_WG MUW
     ON U.ID = MUW.WORKGROUP2USER LEFT JOIN
     WORKGROUP W
     ON W.ID = MUW.USER2WORKGROUP LEFT JOIN
     M2M_WG_QUEUE MWQ
     ON W.ID = MWQ.QUEUE2WORKGROUP LEFT JOIN
     QUEUE Q
     ON Q.ID = MWQ.WORKGROUP2QUEUE
WHERE U.LOGIN = 'johndoe';
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! But I'm confused, I've always used that syntax you and @thorstenkettner are talking about (commas in from clause and wheres instead of joins), I was learned to make my queries that way, and all procedures and SQL code I've seen in the project I'm working is written on that way... and it's not a 1980s project. Why is it better to use joins in the from instead of commas and wheres?

Comment: @JuanAntonioAuñónOchando . . . After two decades, it is time to learn standard SQL syntax.  Because Oracle has been around so long, it has lots of old programmers (in both senses) and lots and lots of code with bad practices.  (I feel comfortable using "old" without insult, being one of them.)

Comment: @Jalpesh . . . I write my code exactly as I intend it to be written.  You read read my style rules in Chapter 1 of **Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel**.